# How to capture sound from audio out in c++

Tags: c++, windows, audio-recording

I need to capture audio stream from the audio output and write it to a file. In fact the way it does fraps.

At the moment I know a few solutions. 
1. WDM Filter Audio driver (exactly know what fraps does not use this method) 
2. Use the "Stereo Mixer" (if there is in the system) and then write as usual through waveIn.

Tell me how this problem should be solved properly. It is no code - just explain the algorithm.

Many thanks in advance to all responded.

Comment: Perhaps you should specify your platform/OS... You're probably on Windows since you mention WDM and fraps, which implies Windows, but it's not obvious.

Comment: Do an internet search for "virtual audio driver".  You'll find something that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `stereo mixer` as the audio source. To perform the record itself there definetely should be some WinAPI functions, or there is DirectX, or you just could use some 3rd-party library — lots of possibilities here.